# Problem of jensen shannon

Tags: neural-networks, gradient-descent, gan

In GAN we want to minimize Jensen-Shannon distance and we use gradient descent. When can't we use this approach? What attribute might the training data and the distribution of the generating network have such that we can't use this approach?

Comment: Sometimes a GAN will produce results that are too diverse/generalized to appear like realistic cases to a human (e.g. generating pictures of realistic cows... except they have multiple bodies per head).

Comment: You can also get mode collapse where the generator tends to generate examples that only resemble certain examples of the original data.

Comment: I doubt anyone has worked out a general rule of inference for determining exactly when you can and cannot use the JS-divergence. Study your actual data as best as you can, and experiment with different models, objectives, preprocessing techniques, and training procedures.